# What was the memory/rivalry of Ravana with Bali's son Bana?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman, ravana, bali

In Valmiki Ramayana Sundarakanda, Ravana's son Indrajeet captures Hanuman using  Brahmastra. Then he was summoned in Ravana's court.  Ravana who was greatly angered due to the destruction of his favorite garden and death of his men was struck with following suspicion in his mind after looking at Hanuman.

[Sundara Kanda chapter 50 verse 2](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga50/sundara_50_frame.htm)

> किमेष भगवान्नन्दी भवेत्साक्षादिहागतः ||
>  
>   येन शप्तोऽस्मि कैलासे मया संचालिते पुरा |
>   सोऽयम् वानरमूर्तिः स्यात्किंस्विद्**बाणो महासुरः** ||
>
> When Mount Kailasa was moved by me, is it the same Nandi the divine bull (attendant of Siva) which cursed me long ago and came here now in this form or whether he is **Bana the great demon (son of Bali)** came here in the form of a monkey.

We know the story of Ravana moving Kailasa and getting cursed by Divine bull of Shiva The Nandi.

- what was the story of Ravana meeting Bali's(Son of Virochana) son Bana?
- Which scriptures mention this story? Which kind of relation did they have? Friendship or rivalry?

Answer (score 6):

I remember watchin a Ram-lila once that shows an episode where Ravan and Banasur come face to face in Sita ji's Swayamvar. Quoting from a report this is how it generally goes:

> रामलीला मंचन के दौरान धनुष टूटने के पूर्व रावण एवं बाणासुर जनक के दरबार में पहुंचे। रावण ने जब धनुष खंडित करके सीता से ब्याह रचाने की बात कही तब बाणासुर ने रावण को काफी भला-बुरा कहा।

Meaning both these Asurs have an altercation at the time of the Swayamvar. This entire [Ravan-Banasur Samvad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3OG0Uxv7YA) is probably based on the [Ramcharitmanas](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=5em1y2PczVgC&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=ravan%20and%20banasur&source=bl&ots=RgAXYZ0c27&sig=uLD5D_uYKowSWsvBJb9s5IpjQhc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihxfur0tvVAhUKPI8KHfsIAm84ChDoAQgyMAI#v=onepage&q=banasur&f=false) which mentions that both of these Asurs were present in the Swayamvar:

[image]

Here's the [original](http://googleweblight.com/i?u=http://hindi.webdunia.com/religion/religion/hindu/ramcharitmanas/BalKand/49.htm&grqid=5ZpEmZaL&hl=en-IN) verse:

[image]

I couldn't find any other source where the two come face to face. Perhaps they did meet at the Swayamvar and had a face off even though the Valmiki Ramayan does not record it.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani check the link its the Ramcharitmanas. BTW the Radheshyam Ramayan also closely follows Ramcharitmanas.

Comment: Ravan did not participate in Sita's Swayamvara.